# QStackedWidget area cleared on ESC in child widget line edit

Tags: c++, qt

There are couple of widgets ( all in UI files ) representing pages for stacked widget. One of the contain QLineEdit field.
When stacked widget current page show this widget and line edit have focus, when ESC is pressed whole area is cleared.
All stacked widget pages are defined in UI file.
Any ideas how to prevent area clearing on ESC?

Qt: 5.9.2

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: After creating sample found what was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake. Each stacked widget was derived from QDialog by mistake. And default handler for ESC for QDialog - is close. Changed to QWidget and it is working as expected now.

Comment: This answer does not serve the SO community because nobody understands your problem, you must provide a [mcve]